# Apache2 Service started twice

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04

My apache2 web-server starts twice and wont bind, so i have to do this:

```
sudo netstat -nap | grep 0.0.0.0:443
sudo kill -9 1243
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Is there any way i can make a script out of the code above so that i can run automatically on start up?

I have Ubuntu 10.04, this happened after an update.

**UPDATE:** 
ports.conf - Could this be cause it:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

could it be listening to 443 twice? or do i need to add NameVirtualHost *:443

Comment: Instead of wanting to write a script to kill the second process, why don't you just focus on figuring out why you have two service entries for apache?

Comment: i cant figure it out... this is the closest ive gotten

Answer (score 0):

You might want to actually address the issue of multiple versions of the apache service wanting to load, and fix the source of the problem, as opposed to writing scripts to patch up downstream issues.

One possibility is that you have apache configured to load from both the `init.d` and `upstart`. This is an old vs new service manager. See this post on [the difference between upstart and init.d](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d).

Check your `/etc/init` and `/etc/init.d` to see if they both contain apache entries. If so, you need to disable one of them. `upstart` is newer, so you should probably disable the older `init.d` (my guess).

Reference this page (amongst others) for info on how to disable or remove the init.d service: [Remove Unwanted Startup Files or Services on Debian](http://www.debianadmin.com/remove-unwanted-startup-files-or-services-in-debian.html)

Comment: k so i checked init and it does not contain any apache2 entries, and init.d only contains 1 apache2 file. maybe its the way i have ports.conf configured... should i add a "NameVirtualHost *:443" entry?

Comment: I added my ports conf file